# MySQL and Openstack Need some query advice

Tags: mysql, sql, openstack

I would like to get some information out of the openstack MySQL database, however my query skills are limited and I think I need to do a join on three tables from two different databases.

The structure of the tables is as follows:

```
mysql> describe neutron.ipallocations;
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| port_id    | varchar(36) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| ip_address | varchar(64) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| subnet_id  | varchar(36) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| network_id | varchar(36) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> describe neutron.ports;
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| tenant_id      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| id             | varchar(36)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name           | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| network_id     | varchar(36)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| mac_address    | varchar(32)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| admin_state_up | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| status         | varchar(16)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| device_id      | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| device_owner   | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> describe nova.instances;
+----------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| uuid                 | varchar(36)           | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| hostname             | varchar(255)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| deleted              | int(11)               | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

As the nova table schema is quite large I have truncated it to just contain the fields I need.

What I would like to do is associate all the instances hostnames (nova.instance table) with their ip_address (neutron.ipallocation table). The instances should have a 0 in there deleted field to show that they are live.

however there is no direct mapping between the two. the link table is neutron.ports.
In neutron.ports the device_id is a one to one relationship with the instance uuid and also the neutron.ipaccolcation port_id

So I have tried the following:

```
SELECT a.ip_address,c.hostname 
FROM neutron.ipallocations a, neutron.ports b,nova.instances c 
WHERE c.deleted='0' 
AND b.device_id = c.uuid 
AND a.port_id = b.device_id;
```

This does not return any results so something is probably very wrong with it.

also tried to use LEFT and INNER JOINS

```
SELECT ni.hostname, i.ip_address 
FROM nova.instances ni
LEFT JOIN neutron.ports p 
INNER JOIN neutron.ipallocations i 
ON i.port_id = p.device_id 
ON ni.uuid = p.device_id WHERE ni.deleted ='0';
```

This query returns the hostnames but the ip_address column is NULL so I think I'm missing something.

I don't really know if I need to use joins for this or could it be done in a simpler way.
If any one has any pointers or a solution to this I would be very grateful.

Sorry for the confusion below is some sample data:

```
select * from neutron.ipallocations;
+--------------------------------------+--------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| port_id                              | ip_address   | subnet_id                            | network_id                           |
+--------------------------------------+--------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| 13433d6d-bf47-476b-a841-324aba4a902d | 192.168.14.5 | b024436e-7c69-42ff-b504-219ce9979792 | 96a8fd64-8a94-476d-b9c8-c28055d39041 |
| 5b66e69f-829d-419e-8116-889e0ad36c35 | 192.168.14.7 | b024436e-7c69-42ff-b504-219ce9979792 | 96a8fd64-8a94-476d-b9c8-c28055d39041 |
| 8e32216f-11db-437f-981d-cfe03e90baed | 192.168.14.4 | 07e516af-1162-4bfc-946b-fdc259b013c9 | bdfdb6d6-c0bc-4bdb-896e-6e5919d232c2 |
| 92a45ed8-a472-4845-841f-604259c07ab2 | 192.168.14.6 | b024436e-7c69-42ff-b504-219ce9979792 | 96a8fd64-8a94-476d-b9c8-c28055d39041 |
+--------------------------------------+--------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

The port_id from this table maps to the id field in neutron.ports:

```
 select * from neutron.ports;
+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------+------+--------------------------------------+-------------------+----------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| tenant_id                        | id                                   | name | network_id                           | mac_address       | admin_state_up | status | device_id                                                                     | device_owner |
+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------+------+--------------------------------------+-------------------+----------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| 9a111d6e4dd0440fab4cc7b610efd2bf | 13433d6d-bf47-476b-a841-324aba4a902d |      | 96a8fd64-8a94-476d-b9c8-c28055d39041 | fa:16:3e:6b:ed:5d |              1 | ACTIVE | dhcpc7e0c2c5-8a56-5b48-a120-03c05bff04a5-96a8fd64-8a94-476d-b9c8-c28055d39041 | network:dhcp |
| 9a111d6e4dd0440fab4cc7b610efd2bf | 5b66e69f-829d-419e-8116-889e0ad36c35 |      | 96a8fd64-8a94-476d-b9c8-c28055d39041 | fa:16:3e:b9:4d:2e |              1 | ACTIVE | 578485e5-9f5f-405c-a09a-24f89b81a43c                                          | compute:nova |
| 9a111d6e4dd0440fab4cc7b610efd2bf | 8e32216f-11db-437f-981d-cfe03e90baed |      | bdfdb6d6-c0bc-4bdb-896e-6e5919d232c2 | fa:16:3e:55:af:d5 |              1 | ACTIVE | dhcpc7e0c2c5-8a56-5b48-a120-03c05bff04a5-bdfdb6d6-c0bc-4bdb-896e-6e5919d232c2 | network:dhcp |
| 9a111d6e4dd0440fab4cc7b610efd2bf | 92a45ed8-a472-4845-841f-604259c07ab2 |      | 96a8fd64-8a94-476d-b9c8-c28055d39041 | fa:16:3e:06:ad:13 |              1 | ACTIVE | 221a44fe-23e6-4003-8170-dafedeeaf333                                          | compute:nova |
+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------+------+--------------------------------------+-------------------+----------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

and the device_id from neutron.ports maps to the uuid in nova.instances:

```
mysql> select uuid,hostname,deleted from nova.instances where deleted ='0';
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+
| uuid                                 | hostname                       | deleted |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+
| 221a44fe-23e6-4003-8170-dafedeeaf333 | host1.test.net                 |       0 |
| 578485e5-9f5f-405c-a09a-24f89b81a43c | host2.test.net                 |       0 |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+
```

Comment: I think the first should work (although it's not the preferred syntax). Can you make a sqlfiddle with sample data?

Comment: Should it be `and a.port_id = b.id` in the first version?

Comment: yes the first query works with a.port_id = b.id, I had been using device_id, didn't spot my mistake because I was sure the sql was wrong. Sorry for the time waste. Just out of interest what would be the preferred syntax for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brent,

The problem we're having answering this question is that we don't understand what data in nova.instances matches data neutron.ports. From your attempts it looks like you expect `nova.instances.uuid` to match up to `neutron.ports.device_id`. If that is the case, your first query should work.

Can you provide some sample data and your expected output? I think that could clear up our confusion.

---

Edit

About your question of preferred syntax, I suspect Barmar was cringing at cartesian joins limited by a where clause. Consider the below query instead:

```
SELECT ip.ip_address
    ,i.hostname
FROM neutron.ipallocations ip
JOIN neutron.ports p ON ip.port_id = p.id
JOIN nova.instances i ON p.device_id = i.uuid
WHERE i.deleted = '0';
```

To be clear, the optimizer should choose the same execution path for both queries, but using `on` clauses makes the query more readable. I also changed the aliases; personally I prefer aliases with meaningful names.

Comment: I have added some sample data, I have the solution now as flaschenpost mentioned in his comment I was just mixing up device_id and id in the ports table.